# git-svn dcommiting a single git commit

Tags: git, git-svn

Given multiple unpushed `git` commits, is it possible to `git-svn dcommit` only one of those commits?

e.g. I have commit foo, bar, and baz, but right now I only want to have bar end up in the svn repo. Is this possible?

Comment: are commits foo, bar and baz already in master branch which is tracking the svn repo?

Comment: In my case, no. But it's good to show how to do it both ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have one sort of crusty answer. You can create a new branch with out foo, bar, and baz in it and then `cherry-pick` bar to the new branch and then `git-svn dcommit` that branch and remove it when you're done. That doesn't seem very elegant though.

So assuming foo, bar, and baz are in branch x and master doesn't have any of them.

> `git branch y master`
>
> `git checkout y`
>
> `git cherry-pick <sha1 of bar>`
>
> `git svn dcommit`
>
> `git checkout x`
>
> `git svn rebase`
>
> `git branch -d y`

If master does have these commits you can reset the head as Sizzler suggests.

Comment: I’d dcommit the main branch and keep those other bits separate. You may be able to use the stash here, too.

Comment: @Ben I'm not sure how dcommiting the main branch would help. I've already got foo and bar and baz as commits in git. They just haven't made it up to the svn repo yet. If I make a new branch and cherry-pick the ones I want then I only get those commits.

Comment: if you work on master and you still want to do it like this you can use: "git checkout trunk -b y" - if that doesn't work for you,  look into the git svn docs and search for the layout options

Answer (score 27):

(The following assumes your work is on `master`.)

First, reorder your last three commits so that `bar` is first.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

An editor will pop up with something like this:

```
pick 498e4f4 foo
pick 71547ae bar
pick abf09c6 baz

# Rebase 4d3fe72..abf09c6 onto 4d3fe72
#
# ...
```

Reorder them in the editor that pops up so that `bar` comes first.

```
pick 71547ae bar
pick 498e4f4 foo
pick abf09c6 baz

# Rebase 4d3fe72..abf09c6 onto 4d3fe72
#
# ...
```

Git will spin for a few seconds and burp up a confirmation:

```
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
```

Now you can temporarily roll back to the `bar` commit (`HEAD~2` means two commits back from `HEAD`) and dcommit it:

```
git checkout HEAD~2
git svn dcommit
```

If you're paranoid like me, you can do `git svn dcommit -n` first to be sure you're only committing what you want.

Now jump back to `master`:

```
git checkout master
```

The last bit is to rebase so that `master` syncs up with svn:

```
git svn rebase
```

It's a little fuzzy to me why this is required, but I'm guessing that dcommitting in a detached HEAD state has something to do with it.

Comment: I find this answer easier to understand than the others. Perfect use-case for `git svn dcommit -n` or `--dry-run`.

Answer (score 13):

git svn dcommit cannot selectively commit bar. if you have directly committed foo, bar and baz  on your master branch then you have to do the following to get only bar in svn.

Assume bar's commit sha is something like 13abc...

and git log master shows all your 3 commits foo, bar and baz.

- you need to create a branch from master

  git branch wip

the wip branch now has foo, bar and baz

- reset the master's head to a commit before any of foo, bar or baz. you can do that using [git reset](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) (read the manual, the differences between hard,soft and mixed options affects uncommitted changes in your working tree)

  git reset --hard (COMMIT-ID before foo,bar,baz)

  (or)

  git reset --hard HEAD~3 (go back 3 revisions)

now your master branch has none of foo, bar or baz. verify with git log.

- now you can cherry pick only the commits you want to dcommit to svn from the wip branch into master. so to get bar

  git cherry-pick wip 13abc (sha of bar commit)

the master only gets the bar commit alone.

- now git svn dcommit should push bar alone.

*Suggested Future usage*

So for git-svn it is preferable not to make commits directly on master branch which is tracking remote svn. do your work on local branches and merge selectively to master before dcommiting.

Comment: I've heard differing opinions about where the merge should happen. The way I do it now, is branch and dcommit and then rebase master. I Keep master as the canonical tracking branch and do my work in other branches. I then push those changes up to svn and pull them down into master. That's how it was suggested I do it in #git on freenode. I was doing it the way you suggest before, but it's an extra step as you need to merge the changes into master instead of just pushing them to svn and pulling them back down with rebase.

Answer (score 2):

I somtimes only want to commit a few commits of my branch. E.g.

```
A-----B-----C------D  
^                  ^
|                  |
svn/trunk          trunk
```

If I want to commit `B` and `C` but not `D` I create a new branch, do a `svn dcommit`, switch back to `trunk` and delete the branch.

While I'm on branch `trunk` I do

```
git checkout -b temp `C`
git svn info // just to check that branch temp is properly connected to svn
git svn dcommit
git checkout trunk
git branch -D temp
```

**EDIT**

Like Stefan commented:

> With an additional 'git svn rebase' it worked well for me.

This is necessary, because the commits that are committed to svn will be rewritten. `git-svn` adds the `git-svn-id` to the commit message and therefore the commit hash changes even if the commit's contents are the same. But since the contents are the same the rebase will not cause conflicts.

PS: I also often **omit the new branch** and just **checkout detached**. E.g.

```
git checkout --detach C
git svn dcommit
git checkout trunk
git svn rebase
```

Comment: With an additional 'git svn rebase' it worked well for me.

Comment: @Stefan yes that's true. I forgit it and will update my answer. The rebase is necessary, because the commits will be rewritten by git-svn. It adds the `git-svn-id` to the commit message.