# Using git-svn, if I have multiple commits not in svn, how do I only push selected commits to svn?

Tags: git, version-control, workflow, git-svn

Let's say I have multiple commits in my local git repository that have not been pushed to svn.  For example, these four commits on master.

```
A <-- B <-- C <-- D
```

A is the oldest commit not in svn and D is the newest commit.

How do I use `git svn dcommit` to only push A and B to svn, but keep C and D only in my local git repository?

Alternate workflows welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been thinking about this, and have a potential solution to my own problem.

I can create a local branch for each discrete task I'm working on.  If I finish one piece of work and am waiting for a code review, I can create a new branch and start working on an independent task.

When a given task is complete, I run `git svn rebase`.  I then rebase my local branch on top of master, fast forward master to the head of that branch, then dcommit.

My problem was that commits A and B were part of one task, and C and D were another independent task.  C and D belong in a different branch, and never should have been committed on top of A and B.

The answers to this question...

[git-svn dcommiting a single git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256189/git-svn-dcommiting-a-single-git-commit)

Seem to indicate that only committing A and B isn't really possible.

Comment: This is exactly the workflow I use; all my commits are in separate branches, and I only merge a branch with master if I'm about to push it to svn

Comment: Oh, and I think 1256189 is talking about it not being possible to commit *just* B; you can't cherry-pick a commit to dcommit

Comment: What you can do is always work on a local-only branch in git, then you can cherry-pick commits from that branch onto the git branch that tracks your svn branch. I've used this exact workflow in the past.

Answer (score 3):

`dcommit` takes an optional argument specifying what to treat as HEAD during commits, so either of these work (where `B` is a reference to that particular commit, either by name if it has one or by hash):

```
git svn dcommit B
git svn dcommit HEAD~2
```

Comment: I've tried this, and it causes problems for me.  Sometimes it only commits A, then craps out.  If A and B get committed, it doesn't rebase correctly, and commits C and D are left as changes in my working copy.

I have git version 1.5.5.6.